# How to find Symmetric and reflexive using javascript

Tags: javascript, discrete-mathematics

For my assignment, I have to find whether the set of relation (that I take from 2-D array) are symmetric or/and transitive.Below is 2-D array for relation, R={(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,1)} //This relation may be change as I take value from input by user.

```
var r = new Array(5);
r[0] = [1,3];
r[1] = [2,2];
r[2] = [2,3];
r[3] = [3,2];
r[4] = [3,1];
```

So what i want to know is how to identified base on this array. I have done for symmetric but it still did not show a correct result. Based on the array it should get output "IT IS SYMMETRIC". I still cannot find symmetric so i cannot proceed on finding whether it is transitive or not.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //row
    for(var j = 1; j < 5; j++){ 
        if(r[i][1] == r[j][0])  
        {
            if(r[i][0] == r[j][1])
            {
                symmetric = symmetric + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (r[i][0] == r[i][1])
            {
                symmetric = symmetric + 1;
            }
        else 
        {
            symmetric = -1;
        }
    }
    //j= j + 1;
}
if(symmetric > 0)
{
    alert("IT IS SYMMETRIC");
}
else
    alert("IT IS NOT SYMMETRIC");
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "symmetric" and "reflexive".  (Hint: there is a property of a matrix that is very easy to test that must be true for either of these conditions to be true)

Comment: i use properties of relation i learn on discrete mathematics where condition for symmetric to be true is if there exist (1,3) then it should have (3,1), as for transitive is if (1,3) and (3,1) then it should have (1,1) to be transitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with two loops on the input array is not efficient. It is better to first convert the definition of the relation to a nested object-value structure so you can retrieve in constant time whether a certain pair is in the relation or not.

For the example data that object could look like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "3": true
    },
    "2": {
        "2": true,
        "3": true
    },
    "3": {
        "1": true,
        "2": true
    }
}
```

Here is how to create that object in linear time and to decide on the symmetry, also in linear time:

```js
var r = [[1,3], [2,2], [2,3], [3,2], [3,1]];

function isSymmetric(r) {
    // convert to object
    var rel = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (!(r[i][0] in rel)) rel[r[i][0]] = {};
        rel[r[i][0]][r[i][1]] = true;
    }
    // Test to see if opposite relation is in object
    for (var a in rel) {
        for (var b in rel[a]) {
            if (!rel[b] || !rel[b][a]) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(isSymmetric(r));
```

#### Transivity

Transitivity needs to consider a third value. When the following two relations hold: a→b and b→c then also a→c must hold. This requires an extra loop according to the same pattern as in the above code:

```js
var r = [[1,3], [2,2], [2,3], [3,2], [3,1]];

function isTransitive(r) {
    // convert to object
    var rel = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (!(r[i][0] in rel)) rel[r[i][0]] = {};
        rel[r[i][0]][r[i][1]] = true;
    }
    // Test to see if opposite relation is in object
    for (var a in rel) {
        for (var b in rel[a]) {
            if (!rel[b]) continue;
            for (var c in rel[b]) {
                if (!rel[a][c]) return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isTransitive(r));
```

## ES6 Versions

Of course this can be written in ES6 more succinctly using a Map, a Set and some other goodies:

```js
const r = [[1,3], [2,2], [2,3], [3,2], [3,1]];

function isSymmetric(r) {
    // convert to Map
    var rel = new Map(r.map(pair => [pair[0], new Set]));
    r.forEach(([a, b]) => rel.get(a).add(b));
    // Test to see if opposite relation is in Map
    return r.every(([a, b]) => rel.has(b) && rel.get(b).has(a));
}

console.log(isSymmetric(r));
```

#### Transitivity (ES6)

The code is the same as in the last code block above (ES6) with the last line changed to:

```
return r.every(([a, b]) => !rel.has(b) || [...rel.get(b)].every(c => rel.get(a).has(c)));
```

Comment: it work for symmetric, thank you, but do you know how to find transitive?

Comment: it can be either ES3 or ES5 sir

Comment: OK, I added it to my answer and changed the ES3 code a bit to use variables a, b and c which makes it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and delete symmetric pairs or reflexive pairs. At the end check the size of the set and if zero, all items have been assigned, either symmetric or  reflexive.

```js
var r = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1]],
    pairs = new Set(r.map(a => a.toString()));
    
r.forEach(([x, y]) => {
    if (x === y) {
        pairs.delete([x, y].toString());
        return;
    }
    pairs.delete([x, y].toString()) && pairs.delete([x, y].toString());
});

console.log(!pairs.size);
```